# UITextView does not display text

Tags: uitextview

In my viewDidLoad I can get UILabels and UITextFields to display text but not a UITextView. Am I doing something wrong in the code below?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

UIView* headerWrapper = [[UIView alloc] init];

//tap gesture is for each section so we can click on it
UITapGestureRecognizer *headerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showContent:)];

header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 738.0, 40.0)];
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

//get the header frame
CGRect headerFrame = header.frame;

//add the gesture
[headerWrapper addGestureRecognizer:headerTap];

//add a label
UILabel* lblSectionTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10.0, 3.0, headerFrame.size.width, 24.0)];
lblSectionTitle.text = @"This is a test";
lblSectionTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];
lblSectionTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lblSectionTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[header addSubview:lblSectionTitle];

[headerWrapper addSubview:header];

//this is the wrapper for the content
UIView* contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, headerFrame.size.height + 15.0, headerFrame.size.width, 200.0)];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UITextView* tvContent = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, headerFrame.size.width, 200.0)];
[tvContent setText:@"This is a content test."];
tvContent.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
tvContent.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tvContent.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet" size:18.0];

[contentView addSubview:tvContent];
[headerWrapper addSubview:contentView];
[self.view addSubview:headerWrapper];

NSLog(@"%@", tvContent.text);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem today and solved it by changing:

```
[tvContent setText:@"This is a content test."];
```

to

```
tvContent.text = @"This is a content test.";
```

At first I thought the problem was with not having my UITextView loaded. But after I made sure it was loaded and connected in the interface builder (not your case since you are doing it programmatically), I could only set its content by doing direct attribution instead of calling setText.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually, [tvContent setText... was my second attempt after trying tvCotent.text...

Comment: Btw, one question, the NSLog you put in the end returns the correct value?

Comment: Yes, I rewrote it all and it worked fine. Not sure what the problem was though.